# Rails composer devise-rails will not let me complete a rails db:reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I used the rails composer tool to create a rails devise composed project, which included rails confirmable.

It was all fine - and then I decided I wanted to perform a `rails db:reset`

I ran the command and this is the output:

```
Andys-MacBook-Pro:myproj andyarmstrong$ rails db:reset
Dropped database 'myproj_development'
Dropped database 'myproj_test'
Created database 'myproj_development'
Created database 'myproj_test'
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
   -> 0.0419s
-- create_table("users", {:force=>:cascade})
   -> 0.0188s
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
   -> 0.0305s
-- create_table("users", {:force=>:cascade})
   -> 0.0236s
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `confirm!' for #<User:0x007fa47ac1c2a0>
Did you mean?  confirm
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/activemodel-5.1.0.rc1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:432:in `method_missing'
/Users/andyarmstrong/Documents/Personal/myproj/app/services/create_admin_service.rb:6:in `block in call'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/core.rb:339:in `initialize'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/devise-4.2.1/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:65:in `initialize'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:66:in `new'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:66:in `new'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:50:in `create!'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:156:in `block in create!'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:337:in `scoping'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:156:in `create!'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:227:in `find_or_create_by!'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:6:in `find_or_create_by!'
/Users/andyarmstrong/Documents/Personal/myproj/app/services/create_admin_service.rb:3:in `call'
/Users/andyarmstrong/Documents/Personal/myproj/db/seeds.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:549:in `load_seed'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:268:in `load_seed'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:181:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:21:in `block in perform'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/andyarmstrong/Documents/Personal/myproj/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/Users/andyarmstrong/Documents/Personal/myproj/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/spring-2.0.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
/Users/andyarmstrong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myproj/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/andyarmstrong/Documents/Personal/myproj/bin/spring:15:in `require'
/Users/andyarmstrong/Documents/Personal/myproj/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Following through the stack trace - I see it is failing in the db:seeds component, on this line : `user = CreateAdminService.new.call`. If i then go into app/services and open the create_admin_service.rb file we can finally see our problem line:

```
class CreateAdminService
  def call
    user = User.find_or_create_by!(email: Rails.application.secrets.admin_email) do |user|
        user.password = Rails.application.secrets.admin_password
        user.password_confirmation = Rails.application.secrets.admin_password
        user.confirm!
      end
  end
end
```

Why is user.confirm! failing to be found? Is that not meant to be part of the base Devise package? For reference this is my user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to try changing the line:

```
 user.confirm!
```

in the create_admin_service to simply be :

```
user.confirm
```

Because confirmable.rb of devise doesn't appear to have 'confirm!' as a method. This allowed the db:reset to succeed, so I can only assume this is a problem with devise-rails composer confirmable example! I have made an appropriate issue on their github.